# C++/CLI generics compilation error

Tags: compilation, c++-cli

I have problem with compilation such files.

**CardSet.h**

```
#include "Card.h"
#pragma once
using namespace System;
using namespace Collections;


generic <typename  C>
public ref class CardSet<C> 
{
public:
    CardSet<C>();
};
```

**CardSet.cpp**

```
#include "CardSet.h"

generic <typename  C>
CardSet<C>::CardSet()
{
}
```

[image]
I am following http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/classes2/Lesson24d.htm

Could sb advice what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Sabeeh: C++-CLI is not C++, do not tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, follow the syntax that the tutorial demonstrates, you don't repeat `<C>` everywhere.  Correct syntax is:

```
generic <typename C>
public ref class CardSet {
public:
    CardSet();
};

generic <typename C>
CardSet<C>::CardSet(){
}
```